# Define PHP var using a global var

Tags: php, ee

I am trying to get a php snippet working within a template with PHP enabled(output).

$uid does contain the {member_id} as expected but the php has not returned the correct result.

**Update** 
I think this is parse order issue.

What is wrong here?

```
<?php
  $uid = "{member_id}";
?>
```

Comment: What EE version? I just tested it on 2.9.3 and it worked exactly as expected.

Comment: 2.7.0 @jchrono-battle

Comment: it is working. But the php is not returning the correct result i will look again as it must be parse order issue.

Comment: I know what's going on. Run  var_dump ($uid) and see that you're getting a string of much greater length. I've run into this before, if I can remember how I overcame it I will post an answer.

Comment: Yes, its returning the following: `string(11) "1" `

Comment: i am expecting `1`

Comment: @jchrono-battle i have checked the parse order sheet and the user defined vars are not parsed until well after the PHP. Not sure what the solution is but thought id notify as i found this.

Comment: Well, if you're playing with house money, I'd try Low Variables as a fix. http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables

Comment: was just reading an article about Low. This is great thanks!

Comment: @jchrono-battle i found a quick solution using the ee() function. Updated with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely is parse order, however as your trying to get a global into a php variable you can forget about tag parsing completely. Try this :

```
$uid = ee()->session->userdata('member_id');
```

Member ID is in the Session class (if logged in), test the group for if_logged_in or not.

FYI, for other global vars, you can do things like this :

```
//Global Variables (Site Label)
$var = ee()->config->_global_vars['site_label'];

//Global config settings (Base URL)
$var = ee()->config->config['base_url'];

//User variables (alternate method)
$var = ee()->session->userdata['group_id'];
```

Comment: I was just updating an answer as i found it and you beat me to it! Thanks muchly though this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: That's totally how I got around this in the past, I just couldn't reach deep enough in my brainspace. Mondays. Good job!

Comment: Glad to help, I know what you mean jchrono-battle about Mondays. I've been having a head-muck all day on Magento overloading. It makes EE "remember how to do..." relatively easy!!